# how to receive user data in a new window in javafx2

Tags: window, javafx, stage

I want to show a new window by clicking (say )on a menu item. The new window would contain two TextFields and one cancel button and one Ok button. When user gives data in the text fields  and press Ok then in the parent window i should receive the values given by the user.

How can i do this?
Please show me with an example code.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

here is the solution, you click window menu then click new window, new window opens with two text fields and ok and cancel button, I get the text value from first text field and display it in the parent window. Let me know if you have any questions, I used singleton design pattern along with MVC. Let me know if you have any questions to run the code.

```
 /*

         * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
         * and open the template in the editor.
         */
        package stackoverflow;

        import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
        import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
        import javax.swing.JFrame;

        /**
         *
         * @author Burak Firik
         */
        public class ButtonListener implements MouseListener{

            String value;

            public ButtonListener(String str){
                value=str;
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

                MainSingleton singleton=MainSingleton.getMainSingleton();
                InputFrame inputFrame=singleton.getinputGUI();
                MainFrame mainGUI=singleton.getGUI();
                mainGUI.setLabelValue(inputFrame.getTextField1().getText());
                mainGUI.repaint();


            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                MainSingleton singleton=MainSingleton.getMainSingleton();
                InputFrame inputFrame=singleton.getinputGUI();
                inputFrame.setVisible(false);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

            }

        }
```

And cancel button listener for the popup window

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package stackoverflow;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

/**
 *
 * @author Burak Firik
 */
public class CancelButtonListener implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        MainSingleton singleton=MainSingleton.getMainSingleton();
        InputFrame inputFrame=singleton.getinputGUI();
        inputFrame.setVisible(false);
    }

}
```

And inputFrame where the popup jframe will display two text fields and two button for OK and Cancel

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package stackoverflow;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
 *
 * @author Burak Firik 
 */
public class InputFrame extends JFrame {

    JTextField txt1;
    JTextField txt2;
    JButton     btnOk;
    JButton     btnCancel;
    public InputFrame(){
        initGUI();
        initHandlers();
    }

   void initGUI(){
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.setSize(300,300);
        this.setLocation(200,200);
        txt1=new JTextField(10);
        txt2=new JTextField(10);
        btnOk=new JButton("OK");
        btnCancel=new JButton("Cancel");

        JPanel northPanel=new JPanel();
        northPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        northPanel.add(txt1);
        northPanel.add(txt2);

        JPanel centerPanel=new JPanel();
        centerPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        centerPanel.add(btnOk);
        centerPanel.add(btnCancel);

        add(northPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH );
        add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }
   void initHandlers(){
        ButtonListener btnListern=new ButtonListener(txt1.getText());
        btnOk.addMouseListener(btnListern);
        CancelButtonListener btnCancelListen=new CancelButtonListener();
        btnCancel.addActionListener(btnCancelListen);
   }

   JFrame getInputFrame(){
       return this;
   }

   JTextField getTextField1(){
       return this.txt1;
   }
   JTextField getTextField2(){
       return this.txt2;
   }

   public static void main(){
       InputFrame frame=new InputFrame();
       frame.setVisible(false);
   }

}
```

mainframe where the newWindow ManuItem located;

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package stackoverflow;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JRadioButtonMenuItem;

/**
 *
 * @author Burak Firik
 */
public class MainFrame extends JFrame{

   private  JMenuBar    menuBar;
   private  JMenu       menuWindow;
   private  JMenuItem   menunewWindow;

   private      JLabel          labelInputValue;


   public MainFrame(){
       this.setVisible(true);
       this.setSize(300,300);
       initGUI();
       initHandlers();
   }

    private void initGUI() {
                // Create the menu bar
                this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
                menuWindow = new JMenu( "Window" );
        menuWindow.setMnemonic( 'N' );
        menuBar.add( menuWindow );


                menunewWindow = CreateMenuItem( menuWindow, ITEM_PLAIN,
                                "New Window", null, 'N', null );
                add(menuBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

                labelInputValue=new JLabel("SELAM");
                add(labelInputValue, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }

    public JMenuItem CreateMenuItem( JMenu menu, int iType, String sText,
                                ImageIcon image, int acceleratorKey,
                                String sToolTip )
    {
        // Create the item
        JMenuItem menuItem;

        switch( iType )
        {
            case ITEM_RADIO:
                menuItem = new JRadioButtonMenuItem();
                break;

            case ITEM_CHECK:
                menuItem = new JCheckBoxMenuItem();
                break;

            default:
                menuItem = new JMenuItem();
                break;
        }

        // Add the item test
        menuItem.setText( sText );

        // Add the optional icon
        if( image != null )
            menuItem.setIcon( image );

        // Add the accelerator key
        if( acceleratorKey > 0 )
            menuItem.setMnemonic( acceleratorKey );

        // Add the optional tool tip text
        if( sToolTip != null )
            menuItem.setToolTipText( sToolTip );

        // Add an action handler to this menu item


        menu.add( menuItem );

        return menuItem;
    }

   private final int    ITEM_PLAIN  =   0;  // Item types
   private final int    ITEM_CHECK  =   1;
   private final int    ITEM_RADIO  =   2;

    private void initHandlers() {
        MenuListener menuListen=new MenuListener();
        menunewWindow.addActionListener(menuListen);


    }

    public void setLabelValue(String str){
        labelInputValue.setText(str);
        this.repaint();

    }

}
```

this class contains the singleton object it is very quick for lazy programmers :))

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package stackoverflow;

/**
 *
 * @author Burak Firik
 */
public class MainSingleton {

     private static MainSingleton singleton=null;

     private MainFrame gui;

     private InputFrame inputGUI;

      //private constructor for singleton design pattern
    private MainSingleton(){}



    public static MainSingleton getMainSingleton()
    {
        // ONLY CONSTRUCT THE SINGLETON THE FIRST TIME
        if (singleton == null)
        {
            singleton = new MainSingleton();
        }

        // GET THE SINGLETON NO MATTER WHAT
        return singleton;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       MainSingleton mainFrame=MainSingleton.getMainSingleton();
       mainFrame.init();


    }

    public void init(){

        // INITALIZE THE GUI
        gui = new MainFrame();

        inputGUI=new InputFrame();

    }

    public void requestExit()
    {
        // WE MAY HAVE TO SAVE CURRENT WORK
        boolean continueToExit = true;


        // IF THE USER REALLY WANTS TO EXIT THE APP
        if (continueToExit)
        {
            // EXIT THE APPLICATION
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public MainFrame getGUI() { return gui; }
    public InputFrame getinputGUI() { return inputGUI; }

}
```

this is the menu listener, when you click new Window this listener will be invoked.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package stackoverflow;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Action;

/**
 *
 * @author Burak Firik
 */
public class MenuListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       MainSingleton singleton=MainSingleton.getMainSingleton();
       InputFrame inputFrame=singleton.getinputGUI();
       inputFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```